# Building a list view in Xamarin.Forms which can run on iOS and Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

[I want to create this view in Xamarin.Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxAED.png)

```
public class HelpModel : BaseStateModel
{
    ObservableCollection<HelpCellViewModel> Help { get; set; }
}

public class HelpViewModel : BaseStateViewModel<HelpModel>
{

    List<HelpCellViewModel> _cellViewModels = new List<HelpCellViewModel>();

    public HelpViewModel()
    {
        this.Title = R.String.main_tabname_help;

        _cellViewModels.Add(new HelpCellViewModel()
        {

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: no. we are not using xml file

Comment: it's xaml not xml.

Answer (score 1):

In xaml you can Declare List like follow

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
            IsVisible="true"
            ItemsSource="{x:Static local:App.BorrowedBooks}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Author}" Font="10" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                     </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
```

Can access it in xaml.cs file as follow

```
public BookList ()
        {

            InitializeComponent ();
            listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
                 var selectedBook = (Book)e.SelectedItem;
                 var bookDetailsPage = new BookDetails (selectedBook);

                 };
        }
```

Comment: i have 2 files one HelpViewModel and HelpCellViewModel

Comment: You must have 2 files with extension .xaml and xaml.cs. Use above code accordingly.